# Building a radar

Tags: java, math, vector, angle

I want to try and build a radar in Java OpenGL. Basically in the method, you pass in the player's current location, angle the player is facing and the enemies location. If the enemy is straight ahead, the red dot(symbolizes the enemy) should be at the top of the circle(radar), which one could say is 0 degrees. If directly to the right, the red dot would be 90 degrees, etc. Basically, I'm try to find the angle between a vector that is shooting out directly in front of the player and a vector from the player to the enemy. How exactly would I go about doing that? I've looked around and found suggestions of atan2(), but haven't been really sure how to use it. If there is a quicker, more efficient way of doing things, please let me know as well.

Edit: I used the method of plotting the points instead of dot product and cos, etc. and I am using the player's position as the origin. But if the distance is greater than lets say a chosen number 70 using the distance formula, how I would make the enemy dot appear on edge of the radar? Anything less than 70 would be within the radar, but any enemy beyond 70, I would want the enemy to be just circling around the edge of the radar, rather than having the enemy dot disappear.

Comment: OP is mentioning `Java` only in one places (and as tag). Answers are general and wide, so could benefit also non-Java developers. Shouldn't this be migrated to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) (or even to [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)) for above reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your players and enemies are represented in some 2D space (or even 3D space, but they move on a 2D plane such as a level ground) with coordinates, I think the simpler way would be to just directly map in the positions of the player/enemy entities onto the radar, and then apply a rotate transform on the radar with the player as the origin, based on what angle the player is currently facing with respect to the true north.

Comment: I used this method. But if the distance is greater than lets say a chosen number 70 using the distance formula, how I would make the enemy dot appear on edge of the radar? Anything less than 70 would be within the radar, but any enemy beyond 70, I would want the enemy to be just circling around the edge of the radar, rather than having the enemy dot disappear.

Comment: @Ali Given player position and Enemy position, you can calculate the distance. If the distance is greater than the radius of your radar, then solve for the intersection point between: a) the straight line between the player + the enemy, and b) the circle representing the outline of your radar.

Comment: What about if I went about it by using a square radar instead?

Comment: @Ali Same idea, but instead of doing intersection with a circle with your line, you do the intersection test with a square (You can define the square as 4 distinct lines)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vectors, you can use the property that the dot product of two vectors is equal to the product of their magnitudes and the cosine of the angle between them:

```
u . v = |u| |v| cos(theta)
```

Where `u` is the direction of your player and `v` is the vector from your player to the enemy.

You're looking for `theta`, so you just need to use:

```
theta = acos((v . u) / (|v| |u|))
```

Note that this will only give you the angle, not whether it is to the left or to the right. To find that, we can take the cross product and see if it is positive or negative:

```
is_left = |u X v| < 0
```